# Yii, datepicker is not stacking options

Tags: jquery, yii, datepicker

So I initially have a datepicker which disables users to select days before the current day.

Then, I decided to add in a function, `DisableMondays` which disables ALL the Mondays.

But when I add the function in, it turns out that I am then allowed to select days before. It replaces the `minDate : 0` function.

The below is my code,

```
<script> 
    function DisableMonday(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        if (day == 1) {
            return [false] ; 
        } 
        else { 
            return [true] ;
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $( "#Booking_date" ).datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: DisableMonday
        });
    });
</script>

<?php $form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'model' => $model,          
        'attribute' => 'date',          
        'value' => $model->date,            
        'options' => array(
            'showAnim'=>'fadeIn',
            'showButtonPanel' => true,
            'minDate'=>'0',
            'changeYear' => true,
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
        ),              
    ));
    ?>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I believe you should be putting the `'beforeShowDay' : 'DisableMonday'` in the `'options'` PHP array, not in Javascript

Comment: I did what you said, but I get `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple.
You have to write `'beforeShowDay' => 'js:DisableMonday'` in `options` PHP array, not in Javascript.

correct syntax is `'beforeShowDay' => 'js:DisableMonday'`

```
<script> 
  function DisableMonday(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    if (day == 1) {
      return [false] ; 
    } 
    else { 
      return [true] ;
    }
  }
</script>

<?php 
$form->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
  'model' => $model,          
  'attribute' => 'date',          
  'value' => $model->date,            
  'options' => array(
    'showAnim'=>'fadeIn',
    'showButtonPanel' => true,
    'minDate'=>'0',
    'changeYear' => true,
    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
    'beforeShowDay' => 'js:DisableMonday',
  ),
));
?>
```

Comment: Gosh~! I'd love to give you a kiss. No homo. Anyways Thanks alot!! Been searching for a solution for a long time.